# Simulate Vehicle tracking in omnet++

Tags: networking, sensors, wireless, omnet++

I want to simulate vehicle tracking in wireless sensor network using OMNeT++.
I have created WSN. But i don't know how to add vehicle object and move that object in that network. I need some ideas or source code.

Answer (score 2):

Although this can be achieved using [Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/), you might find some functionality missing that is relevant to sensor networks (e.g., battery consumption).

Recent versions of the INET Framework contain parts of Veins that allow you to move nodes according to vehicles' movement. See the [documentation of the TraCIMobility class](http://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/neddoc/index.html?p=inet.mobility.single.TraCIMobility.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SUMO** for vehicle mobility simulation, and connect it with OMNeT through **Veins** framework.